# why is a span positioned behind a select clickable?

Tags: html, css

Why is the `span` element clickable even though it's "behind" the `select` element.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2nv8oyd/)

```css
span {
    color: red;
    display: block;
}
select {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<span>test test test</span>
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option>hello world</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's not behind it, it's in front of it, otherwise you wouldn't see its contents

Comment: I think it's more a question of 'Why is the select behind the span despite it's order in the DOM'

Comment: guys- choose the second option in the select- you'll see the select is clearly on top

Answer (score 0):

Because the first option is empty

Clarifying a little what is on front

```css
span {
    color: red;
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    cursor: help;
}
select {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<span>test test test</span>
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option>hello world</option>
</select>
```

But select hello world and it behaves ok

Also interesting: (see where the cursor changes)

```css
span {
    color: red;
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    cursor: help;
}
select {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<span>test test test</span>
<select>
    <option>........</option>
    <option>hello world</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it looks like negative margin which is pulling the select box upwards,in combination with `display:block` alters regular flow (it doesn't depend from `select`) http://jsfiddle.net/k2nv8oyd/2/

Comment: @maioman in your case, span is in front of the div, it *should* be clickable. In the question, it is behind ...http://jsfiddle.net/k2nv8oyd/3/

Comment: span is in front (both in question and my fiddle); what I can't understand is why span's background is behind div, while text is above.. http://jsfiddle.net/k2nv8oyd/6/ (with `display:block`)

Comment: @vals this seems more like an add-on to my question than an answer.  It does not explain why a select element allows "click through" when the selected option does not "cover" the select, or how to prevent it.